# Response header is not showing up in browser although it is getting logged in console - Cloudflare Workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, response-headers, cloudflare-workers

I created a worker with Cloudflare workers to append a new header:

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
  let response = await fetch(request.url);

  response = new Response(response.body, response)
  response.headers.append("Foo", "bar")



  for (const element of response.headers.keys()) {
  console.log(element);
}

  return response
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
});
```

Ignore the for loop for now, I'm using it to log the headers.

[image]

[image]

As seen in the screenshots, the console logs it. However, I am not seeing it on the browser. how should I resolve this?

Comment: Did you also ensure you have attached this worker to the correct route? I've tried your code on my side and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Response Headers you're showing in the screenshot it seems like there are no default Cloudflare headers. You could have missed to either enable Cloudflare Proxy or maybe did not attach the worker to the subdomain.

For the first case, just make sure you turn on the orange proxy for your subdomain.

For the second case,

1. Go to the `Workers` tab under your subdomain
2. Click `Add route`
3. Set the route accordingly
4. Choose the worker from the list
5. Save and test

[image]

Comment: I have deployed the fixes you mentioned, I can see it in the response returned in the preview on the right, but it's still not visible through my browser... Is this normal?

Comment: That's odd, doesn't look normal. It should be fairly straight forward and as mentioned the same code works on my end without any manipulation. Did you also try in an incognito window/without any plugin? Maybe try with a chrome plugin like http header analyzer

Comment: no idea why, it suddenly worked. LOL. probably a laggy system update or smth. thanks anw!